# Some Distinct Subgroups of $S_4$

Tags: group-theory

Prove that there are at least 3 distinct subgroups of order 8 in $S_4$.

I have various pieces, but I'm struggling to put them together. Since $|S_4| = 4! = 24 = 2^3 \cdot 3$, we know from Sylow's theorem that there exists a subgroup of order 8 in $S_4$.

My first idea was to use the natural projection homomorphism to delineate the 3 cosets of $S_4$ mod this subgroup, and claim that the preimage of each of these cosets under the homomorphism are exactly the subgroups we need, but I'm not sure this it the way to go.

I've been given a hint that showing $S_4 / K \cong S_3$ is the big part, where $K$ is the Klein $4$-group. Assuming that I've already shown this, is there a simple way to get the solution? I've had ideas to use the lattice/fourth isomorphism theorem after this isomorphism is shown, but I need some help filling in the details.

All in all, are both/either method a viable solution to the problem, and if so could someone help describe the necessary things I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the isomorphism
$$ \phi : \frac{S_4}{ K} \to S_3$$

Then, each of the three transpositions $(i,j)$ in $S_3$ defines a subgroup $H \leq S_3$ of order 2.

The isomorphism theorem tells you that for each such $H$ there exists a different $K \leq H' \leq S_4$  such that
$$\frac{H'}{K} \simeq H$$

This means that $H'/K$ has 2 elements. How many elements are in $H'$?

Comment: I wish I could accept both, and thank you for answering using both approaches.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternate approach which only uses the Sylow theorems. Hopefully, I am not making any stupid mistakes.

First, note that by writing a permutation as a product of disjoint cycles that each $\sigma \in S_4$ has order $2,3,4$. Therefore, each $\sigma$ generates a $p$-group and hence belongs to some Sylow subgroup. This means that $S_4$ is the union of its $p$-Sylow subgroups.

By the Sylow theorem $n_2|\frac{24}{8}=3$ and hence $n_2=1$ or $n_2=3$.

Assume by contradiction that $n_2=1$.

Note that $n_3=1 \pmod{3}$ and $n_3|8$ thus $n_3 \leq 4$.

Now, the unique $2$-Sylow subgroup has $8$ elements and the $n_3 \leq 4$, $3-$Sylow subgroups have at most $4\cdot 3=12$ elements.

Therefore $S_4$ has at most $8+12=20$ (note that we actually count the identity $5$ times here, so this can be improved but who cares)  elements. **Contradiction**